# what's the character 'n' in BnCameraService and 'p' in BpCameraService meaning?

Tags: android

What's the character 'n' in BnCameraService and 'p' in BpCameraService meaning?

I think the 'n' is refer to “native”.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as [BpInterface and BnInterface](https://github.com/keesj/gomo/wiki/AndroidNativeBinder), from which they're derived.

Bn = base native
Bp = base proxy